# AWS ECS tasks was stopped with reason The Service Discovery instance could not be registered

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to setup an AWS ECS service with service discovery using ansible using the following AWS ECS task definition:

```yaml
- name: (define) Create gRPC AWS task definition
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    family: "my-grpc"
    region: us-west-1
    network_mode: bridge
    state: present
    execution_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::495388981531:role/ecs-runtime-agent"
    force_create: yes
    containers:
    - name: "my-grpc"
      image: "my-custom-grpc-image"
      essential: true
      memoryReservation: 256
      portMappings:
        - containerPort: 9000
      healthCheck:
        command: 
          - "CMD-SHELL"
          - "grpc_health_probe -addr=localhost:9000"
```

and the following AWS ECS service configuration:

```yaml
- name: (deploy-commit) Start grpc service
  ecs_service:
    name: grpc
    cluster: "my-cluster"
    state: present
    launch_type: EC2
    force_new_deployment: yes
    region: us-west-1
    task_definition: "my-grpc"
    scheduling_strategy: REPLICA
    desired_count: 1
    deployment_configuration:
      deployment_circuit_breaker:
        enable: true
        rollback: true
      maximum_percent: 200
      minimum_healthy_percent: 100
    service_registries:
      - registryArn: "my-aws-cloud-map-service-discovery-arn"
        containerName: "my-grpc"
        containerPort: 9000
```

I've also created the service discovery service through the AWS web console beforehand.

When I run it, the service running on the container was able to run with the health check succeeding, but the ECS task was stopped with the following stopped reason:

> The Service Discovery instance could not be registered.

What's wrong here? I can't find any way to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I did not enable DNS queries on the AWS Cloud Map Namespace. After enabling it, service discovery is working and the ECS service ran successfully.